# What happens to Red Skull after Thanos gets the Soul Stone?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, infinity-stones

Presumably, the massive sacrificial altar and a guide like the Red Skull is no longer needed once someone obtains the Soul Stone.  So what happens to the Red Skull?

Comment: It might be addressed in the next movie, so I guess we have to wait and see?

Comment: Can this really be answered until the movie comes out? Since there may be a definite answer, but it's unknown this just strikes me as speculation.

Comment: He lives on Thanos' fist.

Comment: if comics are any source, he could transferred to '[Soul World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul_World)'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As stated by the directors [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Avengers/status/1025583604305256448?s=20) over the verified “The Avengers” account:

> Red Skull is free to leave Vormir, and he is also free to pursue his desire for an Infinity Stone.

This also implies he survived the Snap.

Comment: I wonder if he'll leave in his "human" form or as a wraith.